# SQLCommand Fails When Connection Parameter is Not Set

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand, ssms

I am having an interesting time using the Statement below that reads like this

```
SqlCommand RiskRevalCommand = 
    new SqlCommand("select * from CreditAdmin.dbo.CreditData_Test");
```

I took the SQL statement straight from a query in SQL Server Management Studio, so I know it works in there, but now it causes an exception to be thrown when the program attempts to execute this line:

```
SqlDataReader reader = RiskRevalCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

and the error reads:

> ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

```
SqlConnection xavierConnection = 
    new SqlConnection("user id=FB\\user;"  +
        "password=password;" +
        "server=dataserver;" +
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
        "database=CreditAdmin;" +
        "connection timeout=15");

try
{
    xavierConnection.Open();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}

try
{
    SqlCommand RiskRevalCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from CreditAdmin.dbo.CreditData_Test");

SqlDataReader reader = RiskRevalCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    try
    {
        double.TryParse(reader["Available Balance"].ToString(), out _availability);
        ...
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}

//close the connection
try
{
    xavierConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

What should I change about my SQL statement so that It doesn't blow up, and so that I can still do the TryParsing for the fields?

Also how the heck does this break when [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820582/getting-ugly-sql-query-to-work-in-c-sharp) works?

(It's what was in the place of the `select *` I'm using now)

Comment: What you really need to do is put your SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataReader into `using` blocks. You also need to remove your try/catch blocks. Maybe have one at the top level to ensure that your MessageBox.Show appears. And in that, you should display `ex.ToString()` and not `ex.Message`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to add the SqlConnection in the SqlCommand constructor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx

Like:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(thisSelectStatementString, myConnection);
```

Or as Kirk mentioned:

```
var cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand(thisSelectStatementString);
```

Comment: *Or* just use `myConnection.CreateCommand()` and have it do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're connection is blocked in the try scope above, try this one

```
        try
        {
            xavierConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand RiskRevalCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from CreditAdmin.dbo.CreditData_Test", xavierConnection/*don't forget this*/);


            SqlDataReader reader = RiskRevalCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
               //no need to try-catch here
               double.TryParse(reader["Available Balance"].ToString(), out _availability);
                    ...
            }
         }

         catch (Exception e)
         {
              MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
         }

         finally
         {
              xavierConnection.Close();
         }
```

and also you set the `Trusted_Connection=true` but you already set a `username` and a `password` change it to false,

try this format in your connection string

```
ConnectionString = "server=Server; user id=FB\\user; password=top$secret;" +
            "database=dataserver; Trusted_Connection=false; Asynchronous Processing=true";
```

Comment: Nope, the OP's connection is declared in the outer-most scope.

Comment: yeah, i didn't notice,because the code is full of try catch :D